# JavaFX FlowPane: Let components grow to fill line

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-11

I am using a FlowPane to dynamically allow more components on a screen when the window size changes. Unfortunately the components "per line" of the flow pane don't use eventually available excess space at the end of a line.

[image: Small screen with excess space]
[image: Larger screen]

What I would like to achieve is that all components in a line distribute excess space evenly among them and use it to grow. But since FlexPane does not offer any grow options (or I missed them) does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If all components in a line consumes the excess space, they will have no fixed width. How should the flow pane find out when to wrap?  You could draw a window wider and wider and the content panes would always be wrapped and only increase their width. -- You could implement your own layout pane (perhaps extended from the FlowPane)  that uses the max widths of the components to check if they fit in the line above them. In HTML flex boxes would help and there is a javafx comp projekt called FleyBoxFX. Perhaps it's a solution.

Comment: Well, usually they would be layouted according their preferred width. What I would like to be able to, is let them grow wider above their preferred width, when there is excess space.
But thanks for the hint regarding FlexBoxFX - I will definetly check it out.

Comment: FlexBoxFX indeed manages to scale the elements in a line to make use of the excess space. I am experiencing other layout problems using it, put perhaps that is solvable.
It is a bit unfortunate that FlexBoxFX isn't released and available in the repositories, but at least the code is available.